# Windows XP / IE 7 cannot add Favorites - Unspecified error

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-7, favorites

Hi everyone hopefully someone can help with this.

I am redirecting the location of the users Favorites folder using Group Policy to be placed in their network HomeDrive (H:).

I am having serious issues trying to achieve this with Internet Explorer 7 if a user is trying to add favorites under IE7 it gives out this message

[image: Screen]

Everything works fine under IE6. I have tried reinstalling IE7 updating it etc but nothing works.

I did some research but most of the fixes are for Vista and they say to disable "Protected Mode" but windows XP does not have Protected mode in IE7.

I would update to IE8 but its one of the requirements on this network is to have IE7.

Client PCs

Windows XP SP3 and IE7

Server

Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Since you have redirected IE Favorites to a file server, check server application log. We had McAfee antivirus product disallowing access to .url files at file server. It really blocked just .url files so you could create a text file to favorites but not an URL link. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Start with testing a manually created file in the redirected Favorites location to verify that the permissions are correct.  This seems like a permissions issue.

Comment: its definitely not a permissions problem, the user has full control over that folder and to eliminate any discrepancies i have also added the "Everyone" group to security and given it Full Control. Also bare in mind that it worked for IE6